# Flask module not found

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to import flask to make a database and im 100% sure im in over my head since i have practically just started python. But that aside I tried googling and have no clue how to decypher the programmer lingo to understand how to fix my problem. Does anyone have any ideas? also lmk if thonny is a godawful IDE, and if i should change to something else
[(error message im getting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdpFk.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.
1- We have a standard here to keep everything on stack overflow, which means no external images, try to copy the error here.

2- Use Visual Code, as it is one of the best IDEs, or use PyCharm as it's a python IDE.
3- There is a tool called `pip` that is in charge of installing packages. Open `cmd`/`terminal` and type `pip install flask` and it should work.

Comment: You don't make a database using flask. SO is not the right place for these questions - you need a tutor or mentor to help guide you in your learning. You can use the link in my profile to reach out

Comment: asad awadia, I was under the impression you can use flask-aqlalchemy to create a database

Answer (score 0):

Flask is a framework for web development. Flask can use Flask-SQLAlchemy to "use" Databases. With Flask-SQLAlchemy, you can define models and queries to create your database (tables) and save and access your data

https://medium.com/@shivamkhandelwal555/a-proper-way-of-declaring-models-in-flask-9ce0bb0e42c1

Comment: Yes, that what im trying to use flask/flask-sqlalchemy to make a database in python. I have installed flask through pip on my computer but im getting a module not found error message. I attached it to my og post